# How can I add extra condition to this to count?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

This counts the number of Users whose code's notification is `true`, and his profile's `notification` is `true`

```
@count = User.joins(:profile, :codes => :community).where("profiles.notification=? AND codes.notification=? AND communities.id=?", true, true, @community.id).count
```

I'm using the gem called `acts_as_paranoid` for logic deletion.
With this the line above include the deleted records which have datetime in `user.deleted_at`.

I want to count with excluding those deleted records.
How can I add this extra condition to above?

something like this?

```
@count = User.joins(:profile, :codes => :community).where("user.deleted_at=? AND profiles.notification=? AND codes.notification=? AND communities.id=?", nil, true, true, @community.id).count
```

Comment: That looks right! Have you tested it in the console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also try using a scope on your model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    scope :not_deleted, where(:deleted_at => nil)
end
```

And then do: (Notice `User.not_deleted.joins...`)

```
@count = User.not_deleted.joins(:profile, :codes => :community).where("profiles.notification=? AND codes.notification=? AND communities.id=?", true, true, @community.id).count
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried your scope. but it returned the same number as before. Obviously it has to be decreased though:(

Comment: What is the count of all the records, and what is the count of the scope? In the console: `User.all.count` vs `User.not_deleted.count`

Comment: User.all.count
  User Load (1.6ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`deleted_at` IS NULL)
=> 11

Comment: User.not_deleted.count
   (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND (`users`.`deleted_at` IS NULL)
=> 11

Comment: It looks like you have a default_scope on your model. I'm assuming the `acts_as_paranoid` gem automatically selects the records where `deleted_at => nil`. Try `User.unscoped.count` and see how many records there are

Comment: I'm so sorry about this. I had the problem at different condition. This is my bad. but the scope way that you showed is useful. Thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

That looks right to me, but `user.deleted_at` should be `users.deleted_at`.

```
- @count = User.joins(:profile, :codes => :community).where("user.deleted_at=? AND profiles.notification=? AND codes.notification=? AND communities.id=?", nil, true, true, @community.id).count
+ @count = User.joins(:profile, :codes => :community).where("users.deleted_at=? AND profiles.notification=? AND codes.notification=? AND communities.id=?", nil, true, true, @community.id).count
```

The SQL generated by Rails uses the plural table name (`users`) instead of the singular model name (`user`).